# VNC enable option locked on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-4

i just bought my Raspberry pi 4

Am trying to figure out SSH and VNC access to my RPI, and something is obviously wrong but I cannot google up the situation.

Have *tried* to follow the instructions on the RPi site, but my raspi-config (and preferences menu in the desktop) do not allow me to change the VNC status; in the desktop the option is greyed out and disabled, but according to raspi-config it *is* enabled?

i have followed this [Tutorial](https://www.stevencombs.com/raspberrypi/2016/03/24/mirror-raspi-monitor-on-mac.html) to achieve remote desktop connection the:
vnc server runs, says "New X desktop is raspberrypi:1"
I've run "ip addr" and "ifconfig" at command line, both agree on the IP address, as does my router.
When I try and connect from a machine running vncviewer, it simply tells me it can't establish a connection.

Initially I thought it might be because I was using wifi instead of ethernet, but even that hasn't helped.

Please i will really appreciate it if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Because you followed an ancient tutorial for a different VNC implementation - try the official Foundation guide

Comment: PS you will need to remove the software you installed and install RealVNC

Comment: If you are just starting out and haven't customized much, re-flash your SD card and start over.  Use Raspbian, not NOOBS, and download from here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/  Unless you have special requirements, use the "Recommended software" version.

Comment: @BobBrown i have only installed OpenCV4 on it which took me a whole day. Does that mean i cant remote desktop using ssh and VNC with NOOBS but i can do it with Raspbian?

Answer (score 1):

I started to write this as a comment, but I think it's really the answer to your question.

NOOBS is at least allegedly an installer for Raspbian and other other operating systems.  When used to install Raspbian, it introduces some unneeded complexities.

No matter what approach you take, you have work to do.  You must 1) Either undo what you've done with VNC, or 2) Start over and re-do OpenCV.  Having installed OpenCV once, I'd expect the second install to take at least a little less time.  I can't estimate how much time it might take to completely exorcise the VNC you've installed.

With that said, here's my prescriptive answer:

- Download and install the [current Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) with recommended software.  Use [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to flash the SD card.  You can start with a new card, or flash over the one you're using.
- [Change the password](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/users.md) for user `pi` before enabling SSH.  (Raspbian will complain if you don't.)
- Enable and test SSH and VNC.  You enable them with [Raspberry] -> Preferences -> Raspberry Pi Configuration -> Interfaces tab.
- Use the RealVNC viewer to connect.
- You will be able to address your Pi as "raspberrypi.local" from modern Windows, Mac, or Linux systems because Avahi is installed and enabled by default.  To change this to [somethingelse].local, [change the host name](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/19668676-renaming-your-raspberry-pi-the-hostname).
- Reinstall OpenCV.

You should be able to do everything except reinstalling OpenCV in an hour or two.

As you use Google and other sources for help, check for a date of 2017 or later or a release name that's either Buster or Stretch.  There's a lot of really old information out there that is best avoided.  (Buster is the current release, Stretch is one release back, but should be mostly safe.)